# Context.Arc not drawing on specified coordinates

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw a circle when ever the user clicks and moves the mouse inside the canvas. If I use random coordinates on the `.arc()` draws but if I use the mouse's coordinates it doesn't draw

If I try this:

JS:

```
<script>
        var clicked = false;
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;

        var ye = true;

        function load(event) {

            debugger; var x2 = event.pageX;
        var y2 = event.pageY;

        if (x2 > 10) {

            var num;
        }

          document.getElementById("<% = values.ClientID%>").innerText = "X= " + x2 + " Y= " + y2;

           if (clicked) {

               //debugger; document.getElementById("<% = values.ClientID%>").innerText += " Moving!";
                   debugger; var canvas = document.getElementById("<% = canvasSignature.ClientID%>");

                   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                   ctx.beginPath();
                   ctx.arc(x, y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                   ctx.stroke();                  

                   x = x + 1;

                   y = y + 1;


           }
    }

    function down() {

        debugger; clicked = true;
    }

    function up() {
        debugger;
        clicked = false;        
    }
</script>
```

ASP:

```
<body onmouseup ="up()">
    <div >
        <asp:Label ID ="lblSignature" runat ="server">Sign here</asp:Label>
    </div>
<canvas id ="canvasSignature" runat ="server" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;" onmousemove ="load(event);"  onmousedown ="down();"></canvas>

    <asp:Label ID ="values" runat ="server"></asp:Label>
    </body>
```

This works but if I replace x and y with x2 and y2 `ctx.arc(x2, y2, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);`, doesn't draw. I'm not getting any errors either.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out! Instead of drawing circles I drew lines. On `mousedown`, call `moveTo(clientX,clientY)` and on `mouseMove` call `lineTo(clientX,clientY)` `moveTo(clientX,clientY)` That way when the user clicks I have the initial position for the line, when he moves, assign the final position and update the initial position.

JS:

```
<script>
    var clicked = false;

    var ctx = null;

    var canvas = null;

    function move(event)
    {
        document.getElementById("<% = values.ClientID%>").innerText = "X= " + currentX + " Y= " + currentY;

        if (clicked)
        {    
            ctx.lineTo(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);

            ctx.moveTo(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);

            ctx.stroke();               

            x = x + 1;

            y = y + 1;
        }
    }

    function down(event)
    {
        clicked = true;

        var canvas = document.getElementById("<% = canvasSignature.ClientID%>");

        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.beginPath();   

        ctx.moveTo(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
    }

    function up()
    {
        clicked = false;

        ctx.closePath();
    }

</script>
```

ASPX:

```
<div onmouseup="up();">

        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblSignature" runat="server">Sign here</asp:Label>
        </div>

        <canvas id="canvasSignature" runat="server" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid #000000;" onmousemove="move(event);" onmousedown="down(event);"></canvas>

        <asp:Label ID="values" runat="server"></asp:Label>

</div>
```

Works on Chrome and IE9.

Answer (score 0):

The mouse position must be adjusted as they are here relative to page, though, pageX and pageY are not part of the official standard and may not work in some browsers.

> [pageX / pageY] This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards
>   track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not
>   work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/pageX)

You can use the following code to adjust the mouse position. It uses clientX/Y which is relative to the client window. Then use the absolute position of the clicked element, here the canvas, to find the difference so the mouse position becomes relative to canvas instead:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");             // set this once in global/parent

function load(event) {

    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect(),   // get abs. region for clicked element
        x = event.clientX - rect.left,
        y = event.clientY - rect.top;

    // plot arc
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();                  
}
```

The only drawback is that you have to consider border and padding if you apply that to canvas. Usually avoid applying such styles to canvas, rather wrap it in a container div and apply those styles to the div instead.

Comment: Oops I forgot to replace pageX/Y with clientX/Y. The one I'm testing is with clientX/Y.

Comment: @JoséCorretjer-Gómez ah, well then it is just a matter of adjusting the coordinate using the absolute region of the canvas.

Comment: getBoundingClientRect() is undefined :/ and I placed it on the same method. I even copy/paste the name from the mozilla dev site, just to make sure I wrote it correctly, and still undefined. I'm trying it on chrome, although it says is compatible with chrome 1 and above.